# Does the Kubuntu installer get less attention than the Ubuntu installer?

Tags: 11.10, installation, kubuntu

I have just tested 10 PCs. 4 were with Kubuntu and 6 with Ubuntu. Of the 6 Ubuntu PCs, 2 of them run on Unity 2D. What I saw in this installation was that the installers for Kubuntu were (In the best words I can put it) old school. For example the Ubuntu installer gives you more friendly options that help in installing it in a very easy way using the GUI. The Kubuntu installer looks like something that came from the 90's.

The Ubuntu one is friendlier in general and easier to read. The Kubuntu one well, lets just say is not.

To top that off, 3 of the PCs I tried crashed when running the installer. 2 of them crashes when creating a partition for /home. The other one crashed when I simply clicked next after the first language option. I had to try 4 more times until only one of them appear to accept and continue. The other 2 I just installed Ubuntu on them.

Even the slideshow  in Ubuntu for example mentioned askubuntu as a source for help. The Kubuntu one did not and even had the Audacity to say "If you need help click on HELP in the menu!".

So to be direct and honest about this, the question here is: **Does the Kubuntu installer get less attention than the Ubuntu installer?** and if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Kubuntu developer has a [blog](http://apachelog.wordpress.com/) [explaining Kubuntu's relationship to Ubuntu](http://apachelog.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/kubuntu-is-not-ubuntu/). If you want help, check the [Kubuntu wiki](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/) or [Kubuntu help and support](http://www.kubuntu.org/support).

Comment: Actually link #2 pretty much sums it up.